# Multiprocessing for-loop appending to a list

Tags: python, for-loop, multiprocessing

I'm processing thousands of blocks and want to slow this down a bit due to the `all_processes` list growing too large before the files can be uploaded. I'm thinking there's a few ways to do this whether it be a `sleep`, `queue` or by batch size, all of which I'm perfectly content on utilizing.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    all_processes = []
    for i in range(start_block, end_block):
        t=time.time()
        process = mp.Process(target=main, args=(i,))
        process.start()
        all_processes.append(process)

    for p in all_processes:    
        process.join()
    print('Completed in', (time.time()-t), 'seconds')
```

This is my first time incorporating `multiprocessing` so I'm learning as I go.

Comment: You could use a `Queue` with a fixed maximum size which will block when it gets full.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you meant about "the `all_processes` list growing too large before the files can be uploaded". Below is example code that limits the number of processes to be started at one time by making use of a `multiprocessing.Queue` with a fixed maximum size. The queue will block whenever an attempt is made to insert more that that into it than its max. The `all-processes` list in it is exactly that, and is used to determine when they are all done.

On my system it takes a little over 20 seconds for 1000 processes to each `sleep` for 1 second (because only a limited number of them are allowed to run concurrently).

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
from time import sleep, time

QSIZE = 10
SENTINEL = 'SENTINEL'
START_BLOCK, END_BLOCK = 1, 1_000

def worker(i):
    sleep(1)
#    print(f'{i} finished')

def runner(queue):
    ''' Get args from queue and start a task to process them. '''
    all_processes = []

    while True:
        args = queue.get()  # Remove from queue.
        if args == SENTINEL:
            break
        process = Process(target=worker, args=args)
        process.start()
        all_processes.append(process)

    for process in all_processes:  # Wait for them all to finish.
        process.join()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    args_gueue = Queue(QSIZE)

    start_time = time()

    runner_process = Process(target=runner, args=(args_gueue,))
    runner_process.start()

    for i in range(START_BLOCK, END_BLOCK):
        args_gueue.put((i,))  # Blocks whenever queue is full.

    args_gueue.put('SENTINEL')  # Signal the end.

    runner_process.join()  # Wait for all processes to complete.

    print('Completed in', time()-start_time, 'seconds')
```